# Sending multiple pieces of data from a fragment to MainActivity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I currently have a fragment containing two spinners and I want to send the information from both spinners to MainActivity.  Is this possible?  While  my code works when I send the information from just one spinner, as soon as I try and send the information from both spinners (per below), none of the information appears to be transmitted:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        onNumberInPartyListener = (onNumberInPartyListener) activity;
        onMethodOfSplitListener = (onMethodOfSplitListener) activity;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}

}
```

Do I need to create two onAttach methods, two fragments or is there another way?

Thanks

Update:

So I ended up doing away with the above and instead used an 'Interface' java class to send the information from Fragment 1 to Main Activity, however now I'm having issues sending the information from Main Activity to Fragment 2.

In my Main Activity, I'm sending the information to Fragment 2 with the following code (where 'evenSplit_CalculationFragment2' is Fragment 2 and 'tellMeWhatEachPersonOwesES is the method I've implemented in Fragment 2):

```
//Send data to Even Split Fragment 2

evenSplit_CalculationFragment2.tellMeWhatEachPersonOwesES(eachPersonOwesESString);
```

And in Fragment 2 I've implemented this as follows:

```
//What Each Person Owes (from Main Activity) 

public void tellMeWhatEachPersonOwesES (String eachPersonOwesThisESString) {
amountEachPersonOwesES.setText(eachPersonOwesThisESString);
    }
```

However, I'm coming up with a Null Pointer exception for both of these.  I've tried testing this by substituting 'eachPersonOwesThisESString' with an actual string (e.g. "test") but most baffling of all I still get a Null Pointer exception.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly is happening? Are you getting an exception and ignoring it due to the empty `catch` block? Also, you know a listener can have multiple methods, right? Do you have a reason to have 2 listeners for 1 fragment?

Comment: You should not catch that exception, if you mess up the class casting, that is a programming error that you **should** know about. In fact, it might not work because you forgot to add the second listener to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

```
h = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        // Getting data from Handler
        tvInfo.setText("Data from Spinner1: " + msg.what);
        if (msg.what == 10)
          // do what you need
      };
    };
```

You can use one handler with different `msg.what` codes to distinguish them. Initialise it in activity and send to fragment, it will fire up when you write `h.sendMessage`

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to solve this problem, what I'd do is use an event bus (although if you really want, you can technically use LocalBroadcastManager with Parcelables).

With Otto event bus, it'd look like this

```
public enum SingletonBus {
    INSTANCE;

    private Bus bus;

    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    private SingletonBus() {
        this.bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    }

    public <T> void postToSameThread(final T event) {
        bus.post(event);
    }

    public <T> void postToMainThread(final T event) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bus.post(event);
            }
        });
    }

    public <T> void register(T subscriber) {
        bus.register(subscriber);
    }

    public <T> void unregister(T subscriber) {
        bus.unregister(subscriber);
    }
}

public class YourFragment extends android.support.v4.Fragment {
     public static class SpinnersSelectedEvent {
          public String firstSpinnerData;
          public String secondSpinnerData;

          public SpinnersSelectedEvent(String firstSpinnerData, String secondSpinnerData) {
              this.firstSpinnerData = firstSpinnerData;
              this.secondSpinnerData = secondSpinnerData;
          }
     }

     @OnClick(R.id.yourfragment_thebutton) 
     public void theButtonClicked() {
          SingletonBus.INSTANCE.postToSameThread(new SpinnersSelectedEvent(firstSpinner.getSelectedItem(), secondSpinner.getSelectedItem()); //pseudo code on the spinner part
     }

}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        //...
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.register(this);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSpinnersSelectedEvent(YourFragment.SpinnersSelectedEvent e) {
        String firstData = e.firstSpinnerData;
        String secondData = e.secondSpinnerData;
        // do things
    }
}
```